# How to search for specific maven plugin

Tags: maven

How can I find maven plugin ? e.g I am searching `findbugs-maven-plugin` in https://mvnrepository.com/ but this will search for dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

I am searching for:

```
 <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Comment: I recommend to use maven central search: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfindbugs-maven-plugin

Answer (score 0):

You can find it in the following link:

https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/codehaus/mojo/findbugs-maven-plugin/3.0.5-SNAPSHOT/

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I think you just forgot to setup maven plugin repositories (or maybe you forgot to mention about it)

For example:

```
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>central</id>
      <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
```

also you could read little bit more about **maven pom** format on official [site](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html)